# How can I create a regex that matches a 6[A-Z] character string, with 3 or more non-consecutive or consecutive Cs?

Tags: regex, search

`(?=[A-Z]{6})(?=([C]){3,6})` is what I have tried so far.

I would like it to work like this:
ABYCCC Match

CBTCAC Match

CCTYEC Match

AFEQCB Don't match

CCEEEE Don't match

EEEEEE Don't match

This however just matches strings with consecutive Cs.
I am very new so any help is appreciated. I'm just using the search in Notepad ++

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: Please add examples of text it should match, as well as examples of what it should *not* match.

Comment: I think if you included the language you're working in (C#, Java, PHP etc.) someone could probably suggest a better solution.

Comment: In a six-character string you can't have more than 3 non-consecutive "C" characters.

Comment: Why is `ABYCCC` a match?

Comment: Sorry, the original was not very specific. I've tried to edit my question to fix things.

Comment: Please clarify, do the Cs have to be non-consecutive, or both consecutive and non-consecutive are allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=(?:.*C){3}).*$
```

Use this regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rP5pV8/1

Answer (score 1):

You can check for occurence of at least 3 `C` by using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=(?:[^C]*C){3})[A-Z]{6}$
```

- `[^C]*C` matches any amount of characters, [that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `C` followed by `C`
- the `(?:`...`)` non capture group `{3}` to be repeated 3 times
- `[A-Z]{6}` requires 6 upper alphas.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kB0dR5/2)
*(Note that I put for demo an addional `\n` in the negated class for not skipping newlines)*

Answer (score 1):

So here we go

```
\b(?=(?:[ABD-Z]*C){3})[A-Z]{6}\b
```

This will match any string that contains of 6 Uppercase letters, of whom 3 (or more) are Cs.

It doesn't match:

- strings shorter than 6 uppercase letters
- strings longer than 6 uppercase letters
- strings with less than 3 C but following Cs outside the string

https://regex101.com/r/vV3yS4/2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in Python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("[A-Z]{6}")
strings = ["AABSDC", "CCCASD", "CAVACC"]

def checkC(letters):
    return pattern.match(letters) and letters.count('C') >= 3

for string in strings:
    print(checkC(string))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(.*C.*){3})[A-Z]{6}
```

I swapped the two parts and removed the "lookahead" from the `[A-Z]{6}` so that the expression matches something positive.

Then, to the left and right of "C" I added lazy dots that match anything zero or more times. So you still match three or more Cs and allow for anything between them.

After that, I removed the `,6` because "anything" can be some more Cs.